# Cancelling Futures in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose, I have code something like this (note that my syntax is not 100% correct)

```
// This is how I am collecting the futures:
int index = 0;
for(Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
  try {
   Boolean canCancelOtherTasks = future.get();
   if (canCancelOtherTasks) {
      cancelAllFuturesFromIndex(index + 1, futures);
      break;
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     // handle exception
     break;
  }
  index++;
}

=====

cancelAllFuturesFromIndex(index, futures) {
   for(int k = index; k < futures.size(); k++) {
       futures.get(k).cancel(true);
   } 
}
```

For a specific job, I essentially need to run N callables in parallel, and I would like to exit early after the first callable yields in true without having to wait for the other callables in the list. Note that the futures in the list are already in order of importance.

Would the above work? Is this efficient (i.e. would it help with the overall runtime of my application assuming each callable has a task with different runtimes)?

Comment: Please don't vandalise the question, if you want to delete it then you can click on the `delete` link under the question tags

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: This is a useful question. Why should you want to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to make this a comment but it's a bit wordy so I'm making it an answer to format it better.

Calling `future.get()` blocks the calling thread until the computation is done. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())

So this won't work, as it will just wait until the first future in the list in order is done and then cancel everything else. Assume the we have 3 futures in the list. `future[0]` takes 500ms, `future[1]` takes 50ms, and `future[2]` takes 45ms. With your current implementation, it will wait for the first item, `future[0]` to finish, since you are calling `future.get()` on the first iteration of the loop, which waits an unlimited amount of time for the future to return. It will wait all 500ms, despite `future[1]` and `future[2]` finishing much quicker

One way you could work around it is to use [`get(timeout, unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to only wait on each future in the list for a minimal amount of time and then check the next one. This isn't perfect, as worst case you'll miss the first finished future task while waiting on another one. You'll have to make this loop infinitely until it successfully returns, or else you could end up missing the first execution if none of them happen before you leave the loop.

If you really need to make it stop at the earliest possible time, I would recommend using [Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: Im sorry I should have been clearer, it will wait until the first future in the _list_ is finished. Assume the we have 3 futures in the list. `future[0]` takes 500ms, `future[1]` takes 50ms, and `future[2]` takes 45ms. With your current implementation, it will wait for the first item, `future[0]` to finish, since you are calling `future.get()` on the first iteration of the loop, which waits an unlimited amount of time for the future to return. It will wait all 500ms, despite `future[1]` and `future[2]` finishing much quicker.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer and add more details. I think that is preferable to embellishing your answer via a comment.

Comment: Good point @Abra, don't know why I didn't do that instead. Edited now for more info.